# startactivity in onClick button inside of navigationdrawer not work

Tags: android, onclick, fragment, navigation-drawer

I want to make a startActivity to MapaQRF.java from HomeF.java that is inside navigationdrawer.
I mean, I want the onclick (button) do the same as the onNavigationDrawerItemSelected (in MapaQRF pocision)

fragment_home.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="cl.bikepurranque.www.bikeqrf.HomeF">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Mapa Paraderos QR"
        android:id="@+id/btnMap"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:onClick="onClickMap"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

HomeF.java (Here's the problem)

```
public void onClickMap(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this.getActivity(), MapaQRF.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

NavDrawer.java

```
@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
// update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (position){
        case 0:
            fragment = new MapaQRF();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                    .commit();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new DetectarQRF();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                    .commit();
            break;
        case 2:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Login.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
    }

}
```

---

#### Fixed

The problem was that was calling an activity when I needed to call a fragment.

removed: "android:onClick="onClickMap"" on Button (fragment_home.xml)

added in HomeF.java
(onCreateView) Method
btnMap = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnMap);

btnMap.setOnClickListener(this);

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == btnMap){
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment = null;
        fragment = new MapaQRF();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: post full code of fragment_home.xml

Comment: Your problem seems a bit unclear

Comment: Post your crash log.

Comment: Thank, log helped me find the error in specific

Comment: Please move your solution to its own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `getActivity()`

```
public void onClickMap(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MapaQRF.class);
    getActivity().startActivity(intent);
}
```